# instructions after scanf() call get called twice

Tags: c, loops, io, pthreads, scanf

The following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

char input;

void *
dpy(void *args)
{
        printf("\n[input] = %c\n", input);
}

void *
read(void *args)
{
        pthread_t child;

        printf("Write whatever - press 'F' to end\n");

        do
        {
                scanf("%c", &input);
                printf("begin\n");
                pthread_create(&child, NULL, dpy, NULL);
                pthread_join(child, NULL);
                printf("end\n");
        }
        while (input!='F');

        printf("done\n");
}

void
main ()
{
        pthread_t parent;

        pthread_create(&parent, NULL, read, NULL);
        pthread_join(parent, NULL);
}
```

1. reads characters from standard input and stops at the 'F' character,
   using the `parent` thread.
2. prints the message `[input] = ..` for each character the user types,
   using the `child` thread.

### Problem

each message having the following pattern:

> begin .. end

gets displayed twice after `scanf` call (which is within the loop at the `read` routine), although it is supposed to wait for the next character input from the next `scanf` call.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the problem of scanf() leaving newline, you have a couple of more minor issues.

1. Thread functions' prototype require they return a pointer. So `read()` and `child()` must have `return NULL;` at the end (or other value if necessary - but I don't see you have that need here).
2. `void main()` is a non-standard protype for `main()`. Use `int main(void)` or equivalent.
3. You should also check the return values of `pthread_*` functions; they could fail!

Having a leading whitespace in scanf( `scanf(" %c", &input);`) ignores *any* numbers of whitespace in the input. Hence it'd consume the newline character left by the previous input. But in general, it's better to avoid scanf and prefer `fgets()` instead. See [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)